# How do I display only part of the array after findOne in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, objectid

Restaurants is a collection and has objects like below:

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("61723c7378b6d3a5a02d908e"),
    name: 'The Blue Hotel',
    location: 'Noon city, New York',
    phoneNumber: '122-536-7890',
    website: 'http://www.bluehotel.com',
    priceRange: '$$$',
    cuisines: [ 'Mexican', 'Italian' ],
    overallRating: 0,
    serviceOptions: { dineIn: true, takeOut: true, delivery: true },
    reviews: [
      {
        _id: new ObjectId("61736a0f65b9931b9e428789"),
        title: 'asd',
        reviewer: 'khoh',
        rating: 3,
        dateOfReview: '5/12/2002',
        review: 'hey'
      },
        _id: new ObjectId("61736a0f65b9931b9e428790"),
        title: 'dom',
        reviewer: 'firuu',
        rating: 4,
        dateOfReview: '25/1/2002',
        review: ' bruh'
      }
    ]
  }
```

I am using the below code to find this object based on the review id provided

```
async get(reviewId) {

    const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
    reviewId = ObjectId(reviewId)
    const r = await restaurantsCollection.findOne({reviews: {$elemMatch: {_id: reviewId}}})
    return r
```

This returns the whole object from the restaurant collection, what do I do if I want only the review displayed whose id is provided in get(reviewID)

Output:

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId("61736a0f65b9931b9e428790"),
   title: 'dom',
   reviewer: 'firuu',
   rating: 4,
   dateOfReview: '25/1/2002',
   review: ' bruh'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a projection, specify the fields to return

The following returns only the review whose id is provided in get(reviewID)

```
async get(reviewId) {
  const restaurantsCollection = await restaurants();
  reviewId = ObjectId(reviewId)

  const r = await restaurantsCollection.findOne(
    { reviews: { $elemMatch: { _id: reviewId } } },
    { "reviews.$": 1 }
  )

  return r
}
```

[Test Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xn-elYyMkR9)

> You can also use find instead of fineOne

Comment: It returns all the reviews, I want to display only the matched review

Comment: Hi, I have updated the code. Please check @swombhai

Comment: I still get the entire object when I return r, not sure why

Comment: the [findOne](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.0/interfaces/findoptions.html) method of node js as far as i know takes the projection as option,so it should replaced by  `{"projection" : { "reviews.$": true }}` test it maybe

Comment: Is there a way to represent the _id with a string instead of new ObjectID? Can toString() be added to findOne function?

Answer (score 1):

Query

- replace the `ObjectId("61736a0f65b9931b9e428789")` with `reviewId`
- this will return the reviews that match the `_id` in an array
- if you want to get the first only, in case there is always max 1
  you can replace the last project with
  `{"$project": {"_id": 0, "review": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$reviews", 0]}}}`

*not sure if this is what you need

[Test code here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mcNuRpBZbLD)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"reviews._id": ObjectId("61736a0f65b9931b9e428789")}}
 {"$set": 
   {"reviews": 
     {"$filter": 
       {"input": "$reviews",
        "cond": 
        {"$eq": ["$$this._id", ObjectId("61736a0f65b9931b9e428789")]}}}}},
  {"$project": {"_id": 0, "reviews": 1}}])
```

Comment: Do I have to put toArray() anywhere? I replaced the code but didn't get the output

Comment: yes aggreagte will return a cursor , use  `result.toArray()`

Comment: the @Pramisha answer looks more like your code, i think use the other answer, this is aggregate solution, here you can do it with find only.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct answer of your question but you can try something like this.

```
const r = await restaurantsCollection.findOne({reviews: {$elemMatch: {_id: reviewId}}})?.reviews.find(review => review._id.equals(reviewId))
```